# I'm trying to run the rearrange_name function to rearrange the variable "name" but i keep getting the "NoneType" error

Tags: python, regex, unit-testing, nonetype

```
import re

def rearrange_name(name):
    result= re.search(r'^([\w.]*),([\w.]*)$', name)
    return '{} {}'.format(result[2], result[1])

print(result=rearrange_name('Lovely Ada'))
```

[The NoneType error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaeFX.png)

Comment: Are you sure the pattern is correct?

Comment: You should be checking that your pattern actually matched the string (hint: it didn't) before attempting to use the result of the match. What you're trying to do would be more easily achieved with `split` anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space separating the groups is not being captured by your regex pattern

```
import re

def rearrange_name(name):
    result= re.search(r'^(\w*)[ ,](\w*)$', name)
    return '{} {}'.format(result[2], result[1])

print(rearrange_name('Lovely Ada'))
```

Comment: It worked. I added '\s' to capture the whitespace between groups.

Comment: if you just want to reverse words there are easier ways than using regex.  Fo example if you have a string containing words separated by spaces then you could use `reversed_words = ' '.join(reversed(words.split()))`

Comment: Glad to hear - please accept this answer if it has helped you